# Apply style to ButtonBase in a Tab component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am trying to figure out Material UI style overriding with a nested component. Say I want to increase bottom border height on a active `Tab`. This border is applied by the underlying `ButtonBase`.

Here is the style definition:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    // an example brutal overriding, not clean, I'd like a better approach for the button
    "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
      marginRight: "8px"
    }
  },
  // override Tab
  tabWrapper: {
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  tabSelected: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.main
  },
  tabLabelIcon: theme.mixins.toolbar, // same minHeight than toolbar
  // TODO override buttonBase ???
  // ...
}));
```

An example usage:

```
      <Tab
        value="/"
        classes={{
          wrapper: classes.tabWrapper,
          selected: classes.tabSelected,
          labelIcon: classes.tabLabelIcon
        }}
        icon={
          <React.Fragment>
            <DashboardIcon />
          </React.Fragment>
        }
        label="Home"
        // TODO: is this the expected syntax? TypeScript is not happy with this prop...
        buttonBaseProps={{ classes: {} }}
      />
```

I have no idea how to define the `ButtonBase` classes in this example.

How should I define my props to override the `ButtonBase` style?

Edit: doc is here https://material-ui.com/api/tab/, the last section describe the inheritance process but the documentation is very terse.

Edit 2: the example use case is bad as you should override `".MuiTabs-indicator"` to increase the bottom border height (it's actually an additional span not a border) but the question stands. Imagine that I want to change the `ButtonBase` background-color for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turns out, There is no separate ButtonBase component inside the Tab component. So you won't find prop called **buttonBaseProps**. The tab itself is rendered as the button component.

Whatever style you wanna pass, pass it to the root inside classes. See below

```
 <Tab classes={{
          root: classes.customButtonBaseRoot,
          wrapper: classes.tabWrapper,
          selected: classes.tabSelected,
          labelIcon: classes.tabLabelIcon
        }}
      />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/apply-style-to-buttonbase-in-a-tab-component-izgj5

Comment: So when they say "The props of the ButtonBase component are also available. You can take advantage of this behavior to target nested components.", they mean that the Tab is a button component itself?